# How to specify limits with kubectl run when using stdin

Tags: kubernetes

I'm invoking Kaniko (I Docker image that can build Docker images) successfully in this way (EKS environment):

```
cat build.tar.gz | kubectl run kaniko-httpd-ex --quiet --stdin --rm --restart=Never --image=748960220740.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kaniko:0 --env=AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true -- --destination=748960220740.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/httpd-ex:23-04-26_08-54-DV-6525-kube --context tar://stdin --label commit=8e3a236f702c689891a50a60acf7e05658fa3939 --label build_url=Sin-Jenkins
```

This works ok, except when there is no enough ephemeral storage available.

Now I want to specify limits, like `ephemereal-storage`.
As the `--limits` option has been removed in recent versions of Kubernetes, I have to use the `--overrides`, and I have to change many things.

Here is how I do it:

```
cat build.tar.gz | kubectl run kaniko-httpd-ex --quiet --restart=Never -i --rm --image=748960220740.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kaniko:0 --overrides='{"apiVersion":"v1",
"spec":
{"containers":[{
  "name":"kaniko",
  "stdin": true,
  "restartPolicy":"Never",
  "image":"748960220740.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kaniko:0",
  "env":[{"name":"AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG","value":"true"}],
  "resources":{"requests":{
    "ephemeral-storage":"116Mi",
    "memory": "50Mi",
    "cpu": "50m"
  }},
  "args":[
    "--destination=748960220740.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/httpd-ex:23-04-26_08-57-DV-6525-kube",
    "--context","tar://stdin"
    ,"--label","commit=8e3a236f702c689891a50a60acf7e05658fa3939","--label","build_url=Sin-Jenkins"]
}]}'
```

It launches correctly kaniko, but after 65 seconds, kaniko is killed and the only error message is:

```
error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

```
$ kubectl get ev | grep kaniko
19m         Normal   Scheduled   pod/kaniko-httpd-ex   Successfully assigned sbt-david/kaniko-httpd-ex to ip-10-120-134-171.eu-west-1.compute.internal
19m         Normal   Pulled      pod/kaniko-httpd-ex   Container image "748960220740.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kaniko:0" already present on machine
19m         Normal   Created     pod/kaniko-httpd-ex   Created container kaniko
19m         Normal   Started     pod/kaniko-httpd-ex   Started container kaniko
17m         Normal   Killing     pod/kaniko-httpd-ex   Stopping container kaniko
```

How to specify limits on resources when using `stdin`?

Related info:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1101

Notes:

- I cannot use the `--limits` flag from `kubectl run` as it has been removed recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs ok, and I can set limits if I do:

```
kubectl apply -f kaniko.yaml
kubectl wait pod/kaniko --for condition=Ready --timeout=10m
kubectl attach kaniko -i
kubectl get pod/$pod -o jsonpath='{.status.containerStatuses[*].state.terminated.exitCode}'
```

So, for advanced uses, `kubectl run` isn't appropiate, at least with version 1.27.1.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample:

```
...
"resources":{"requests":{
    "ephemeral-storage":"116Mi"},  # <-- incorrect
...
```

Try:

```
...
"resources":{
  "requests":{
    "ephemeral-storage": "116Mi",
    "memory": "50Mi",
    "cpu": "50m"
  },
...
```

Here's a working example that runs a pod for 5m. Do `kubectl describe pod busybox` and check the `Requests` section:

```
kubectl run busybox --image busybox --overrides '
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "spec": {
     "restartPolicy": "Never",
     "containers": [
      {
        "name": "busybox",
        "image": "busybox",
        "command": ["ash", "-c", "sleep 300"],
        "resources": {
          "requests":{
            "ephemeral-storage": "116Mi",
            "memory": "50Mi",
            "cpu": "50m"
 }}}]}}'
```

Comment: Good point!, it is really a bug in my JSON. but this doesn't solve my nasty `error: timed out waiting for the condition`

Comment: After you fix your spec and Kaniko doesn't run, good chance that the error is due to Kaniko and not k8s.

Comment: `Kaniko` works always ok if I use the form without `overrides`  And the error message looks like it comes from Kubernetes.

Comment: Is your sample yaml in the question the final one? 50Mi memory may be too low.

Comment: I've measured a RAM consumption of 42 Mi with `kubectl top po`.  But what it worries me is the timeout error.